# Meaning of 5th of the Sheva Brachos

Tags: blessing, marriage, drush, sheva-brachos

One of the Sheva Brachos we say is:

> שמח תשמח רעים האהובים, כשמחך יצירך בגן עדן מקדם. ברוך אתה ה', משמח חתן וכלה.‏
>   Grant perfect joy to these loving companions, as you did your creations in the Garden of Eden. Blessed are You, LORD, who grants the joy of groom and bride. (Translation from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheva_brachot#The_wording))

What is the Perfect Joy that was in the Garden of Eden that we aspire to for our Bride and Groom?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few answers are given first the Pardes Yosef in Parshas Breisheis. He says that alot of the arguments couples have are about the Bride and groom thinking that they come from a better family, hence it leads to arguments so here we Bless them as in The Garden Of Eden you where both were created By G-d nothing to argue about!!!
A second answer is offered by The Klausnberger Rebbe he said we bless them to live as in the situation of the Garden Of Eden as in Gan Eden there where no Monetary problems or Keeping up with the Freidman's as they lived alone and as it says in the Gemara Sanhedrin Nun Tes amud Beis that the Angels would Roast for Adam meat and pour him wine so there where no problems of making a living another cause of fighting between Couples that would be prevented.Thearby the Bracha is Easily understood.
Another Answer I thought of similar to the first is a very dominant cause of fights between couples is the In-Laws(who should be called Out-Laws)mixing in to the Couples lives with **"SUGGESTIONS"** here we bless them like Gan Eden where there where no In-Laws.

Comment: Maybe Adam and Hava had it worse regarding in-laws because they did not just not act human, they actually weren't! (That's if you want to work some sort of theory of evolution into Maaseh B'reishis) ;-)

Comment: There's an old jewish joke. Q: Who was the happiest person in history? A: Adam, he had no mother-in-law.

Comment: Tangential, but how can the Gemara Sanhedrin 59b say angels roasted meat for Adam?  He was not allowed to eat meat!

Comment: "who should be called Out-Laws". I'm not saying that in-laws never cause problems. But, despite your attempt at humor, note that numerous couples who don't get along with their in-laws have no problem needing them to watch the grandkids while the couple escapes for a two week cruise. So, they can't be "out laws" when you need them.

Answer (score 4):

Rashi ([TB Kesuvos 8A](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=15&daf=8&format=pdf), s.v. M'sameah Hasan V'chalah, toward the end) says that the point of this blessing is wishing the couple success and happiness in worldly things such as *parnassah* (making a living) etc. the same way Hashem gave happiness to Adam in the Garden of Eden of old. If that is the case then according to Rashi, it is referring to how Hashem provided Adam with all of his worldly needs in Gan Eden.